# Shell script musn't generate "extra" error messages, but is for one odd test case

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I must write a basic script that takes input in the form of:

./chext 'param1' 'param2.xx'

and outputs:

param2.param1

specifically, I have to check to see if the file exists, and if it does, rename it with the new extension, and if it does not, generate the message:

param2.xx: No such file

specifically, I'm told that: "No other messages should be issued, including error messages from commands invoked by your script."

This works fine with examples like:

./chext 'com' 'aardvark.dat'

and

./chext 'ret' 'too common.exp'

but for:

./chext 'dat' 'ocelot.dat'

I'm getting the error (created by my professor) "generated unexpected messages"

Can anyone tell me what's so different about this example that my script isn't taking care of?

```
#!/bin/csh                                                                      
set ext="$1"
set oldName="$2"
if (-r "$oldName") then
set newName=`echo "$oldName" | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".$ext"'/g'`
mv "$oldName" "$newName"
else
echo "$oldName": No such file
endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename a file to the name it already has.

Comment: Do you know what I should do?

Comment: You should check whether or not the names are the same.

Comment: Even if the extension makes the name the same, it isn't originally in my relative path, so it should still give the correct error message I'm giving. I don't understand what other "messages" are being generated.

Comment: `$ mv t.txt t.txt`
`mv: \`t.txt' and \`t.txt' are the same file`

Comment: Ah, is there a way to either not print this error or check for similarity, then say "do nothing"? I'm not sure of the equivalent of "do nothing" to add to my script that would satisfy the check.